# Create an artisan command for generating custom classes or files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What's the best way ( or maybe the way it's actually done ) of creating an artisan command for generating custom classes or files? Like `php artisan make:console` itself that creates a php class for our new artisan command.

From what I can think of, we have two options:

- Add the template for that new file using php heredoc(or any string inside the new command's class file for that matter), which is really messy.
- Put a template file somewhere, read it, replace what's necessary, and then create the new file. But I don't know where would be best to put the template file.

So is there a best-practice for handling this situation in Laravel? I googled it, but there was only articles and documentation for simple artisan command creation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Laravel uses `.stub` files as templates, and replaces the tokens inside the template.

Since you mentioned the `make:console` command, for reference you can take a look at the following files:

- `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/console.stub`
  ([on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/console.stub))
  This the template for making new console commands.
- `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConsoleMakeCommand.php`
  ([on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ConsoleMakeCommand.php))
  This is the code that is executed when you run the `php artisan make:console` command.

If you want to take a look at packages that have done this, as well, a good example is the [generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) package by Jeffrey Way at Laracasts.

Comment: Good job @patricus. I looked in vendor too, but I guess I wasn't thorough enough :-). so I'll put mu stub files in `app\Console\Commands\stubs`. Thanks man

Comment: This is a lifesaver! Thank you

Answer (score 23):

Update 04/2020: Laravel 7 comes with a way to edit the default stubs to make changes to them and have Laravel pick up those changes. If you want to make a completely different stub to publish a totally different file the process below is appropriate otherwise look at the docs at the link below.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#stub-customization

---

I know this question is a bit old but this is pretty easy if you just want to create a similar file that Laravel already does. (I wanted to create a job with some custom traits attached on creation)

So first look at the stubs Laravel comes with [here on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs).

Next, pick the stub of the type of class you want (I copied the [job-queued stub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/job-queued.stub)) and paste it somewhere you can access in your app. I put mine inside `App\Console\Stubs` since that makes sense that commands will use the stubs.

After that, create your artisan command with `php artisan make:command commandName`.

Inside the command created use this file `Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand`. Now make your command extend this class instead of `Command`; This class is the class Laravel uses to create classes and it extends `Command` itself.

Inside your command create a few properties and methods as follows:

```
protected $name = 'make:custom-file'; The name of your command. This replaces $signature

protected $description = 'Command description.';

protected $type = 'Job'; Type of class to make

//location of your custom stub
protected function getStub()
{
    return  app_path().'/Console/Stubs/custom-job.stub';
}

//The root location the file should be written to
protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
{
    return $rootNamespace.'\Jobs';
}

//option flags if any see this for how it works
protected function getOptions()
{
    return [];
}
```

A full example of how the class should look is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;

class CustomJob extends GeneratorCommand
{

    /**
    * The name and signature of the console command.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $name = 'make:custom';

    /**
    * The console command description.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $description = 'Create a custom job.';

    /**
    * The type of class being generated.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $type = 'Job';

    /**
    * Get the stub file for the generator.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return  app_path().'/Console/Stubs/custom-job.stub';
    }

    /**
    * Get the default namespace for the class.
    *
    * @param  string  $rootNamespace
    * @return string
    */
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace.'\Jobs';
    }

    /**
    * Get the console command options.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Once you run your custom artisan command it will write your custom stub to where you specify.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for sharing this! Awesome +1

Comment: Thank you for this informative post. I have a related question, which I couldn't find a good answer: How can I create a command to make a blade file in views folder?

Comment: @Lamar you would simply create a stub to use as a template and set the path of `getDefaultNamespace` to publish to the views folder. Laravel 7 and higher now has a way to create components from the command line 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components